# why Xcode 6.1 not generating distribution IPA?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Hi developed one simple iOS application i also have apple developer account i created Distribution certificates and distribution provision profile i test with my iPhone 4s and app working fine but when i tried to archive application and try to export with "Save for Ad Hoc development" it show me this message "You are not registered as an apple developer. Please visit the Member Center to Register." and most funny thing is my apple account is only 4 months old. I googled lot but dont find any solution please help me out. I also tried to generate IPA from two different mac system with different Distribution Certificate.

[image: Screen Shot when i tried to generate IPA]

Comment: Did you tried close/open Xcode? May be you need to contact Apple support for this issue.

Comment: yes i tried and also restarted mac more than 2 time but not solved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i found solution for it i removed all my certificates and provision profile from my apple developer account and than i tried and i found solution its very funny but i found solution.

Comment: It was Xcode bug, sometimes it makes crazy... >_<